# ForeignKey(unique=True) is usually better served by a OneToOneField

Tags: django, django-models, makemigrations

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    id = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return Categories.name

    class Meta:
        order_with_respect_to = 'id'


class Specializations(models.Model):
    id = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return Specializations.name
```

courses.Categories.id: (fields.W342) Setting unique=True on a ForeignKey has the same effect as using a OneTo
OneField.

```
    HINT: ForeignKey(unique=True) is usually better served by a OneToOneField.
```

courses.Courses.id: (fields.W342) Setting unique=True on a ForeignKey has the same effect as using a OneToOne
Field.

```
    HINT: ForeignKey(unique=True) is usually better served by a OneToOneField.
```

courses.Specializations.id: (fields.W342) Setting unique=True on a ForeignKey has the same effect as using a
OneToOneField.

This warning or error raises although the relation is one to many !! not one to one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you designed your models it is essentially a `OneToOne` relationship, because you set the `ForeignKey` to be the `primary_key` (this automatically aplies `unique=True`).

Do you really want to the user to be the `primary_key` of `Categories` or `Specializations`?

I think you want something like this:

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Specializations(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

With this a `User` can have many `Categories` and `Specializations`
I also changed the `__str__` method to `self.name`

Comment: ERRORS:
courses.Categories: (models.E004) 'id' can only be used as a field name if the field also sets 'primary_key=T
rue'.
and repeated for all tables

Comment: remove the id fields. Django creates them per default. `id` is a reserved name in django. You can't use it as field name